# GSpread Cell Merging

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to merge cells in Gsheets using Gspread for Python, however I can't find any documentation.

I have used the gspread_formatting module to format the text and colour of the cell, but I can't find anything to do with merging of the cells.

I haven't wrote any code because I can't find any examples.

I want to be able to merge the cells based on a range.

Can anyone please help me?

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You want to know how to merge cells of Google Spreadsheet using gspread.
- You have already been able to put and get values to the Spreadsheet using gspread.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In this modification, `batch_update()` method is used.

#### Sample script:

Please set `spreadsheetId`, `sheetName` and the gridrange of `range`.

```
spreadsheetId = "###"
sheetName = "Sheet1"

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
ss = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = ss.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "mergeCells": {
                "mergeType": "MERGE_ALL",
                "range": {  # In this sample script, all cells of "A1:C3" of "Sheet1" are merged.
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 3,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 3
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
res = ss.batch_update(body)
```

#### Note:

- Please set the range as the gridrange.
- In this sample script, all cells of "A1:C3" of "Sheet1" are merged.
- When `MERGE_ALL` is changed to `MERGE_ROWS`, the rows of "A1:C1", "A2:C2" and "A3:C3" are merged.
- When `MERGE_ALL` is changed to `MERGE_COLUMNS`, the columns of "A1:A3", "B1:B3" and "C1:C3" are merged.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [MergeCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#mergecellsrequest)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)

If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Worked flawlessly! I am going to make a function to de-clutter the process. Really appreciate the help :D

Comment: @Dylan Logan Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Gspread now has documentation available for merging cells [on this page](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=merge#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.merge_cells).

If your worksheet's name is my_ws and you wish to merge cells A1 to A5, you could enter the following:

`my_ws.merge_cells(A1:A5, merge_type='MERGE_ALL')`