# How can we delete rows in Google Spreadsheet in Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to delete rows that column B date is less than 30 days.

I can correctly print the rows I want to eliminate with `print(row)` on the following code. but the `sheet.delete_row()` does not work with the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'delete_row'`

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import datetime


service_account_file = 'keys.json'
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

credential = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file, scopes=scopes)

spreadsheet_id = ‘testtesttesttest’
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credential)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range='database!A2:J').execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(30)

for row in values:
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], '%d/%m/%Y') < date:
       sheet.delete_row()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete rows in google spreadsheet using SHEET API v4 by Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168301/how-to-delete-rows-in-google-spreadsheet-using-sheet-api-v4-by-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `spreadsheets().batchUpdate()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56168791/3214422), `delete_row` seems like used by `gspread` (another Python API for Google Sheets)